# Index getting created successful in Elasticsearch but docs.count getting 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, elasticsearch

```
client.indices.delete({index: _index});

    client.indices.create({
        index: _index,
        body: {
            "settings": {
                "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "autocomplete_filter": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": 1,
                            "max_gram": 10
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "autocomplete_filter"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "mappings": {
                "employee": {
                    "properties": {
                        "title": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
                            }
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "fields": {
                                "autocomplete": {"type": "string", "index_analyzer": "autocomplete"}
                            }
                        },
                        "interests": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "createdBy": {
                            "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }, function (error, response) {

       var body = [];
        Feed.find({},function(err, result){
          if(err) throw err;
          else{
            var jdata = JSON.stringify(result);
            var jsondata = JSON.parse(jdata);
           // console.log("result>>>"+result);
            jsondata.forEach(function(item){
           body.push({"index": {"_index": _index, "_type": _type}});
            body.push(item);
          })
}
client.bulk({
                    body: body
                }, function (err, resp) {
                    console.log('Indexing Completed!');
                })
        })
    })
    client.count({_index: 'company',_type: 'employee'},function(err,resp,status) {  
  console.log("constituencies",resp);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Alsatian ,fist time i am upload any question on stackoverflow can you understand the problem with the help of my code.

Comment: @Alsatian this is my right format of code.please look into it ,its working fine and i am also getting console 'Indexing Completed!' but when i check it using command 'curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'' it show the name of index but problem is docs.count is showing  0.

Comment: Your code was not recognized as code by the formatting. I edited it to be more readable. I won't look into it, I'm not an Elastica expert, I just came here because all first posts are reviewed by older users.

Comment: ok thanks @Alsatian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now my problem is resolved......**

In mongoose doc there is _id parameter.During the indexing of doc in elastic search it generate the by default _id. So yo need to give the path of _id in mapping. like

```
"_id": {
        "path": "_id"
        },
```